# Dialer Activity is crashing sometimes on the LG GT 540 running 2.1

Tags: android

This seams to happen maybe one time in 10 only on a older phone (LG GT 540 running 2.1)  The newer phones don't appear to have this issue.

Im launching the activity in the usual way:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("tel:4444");
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, uri);
startActivity(callIntent);
```

The crash log would report the dialier app (not my app) crashed:

```
    09-08 10:45:27.157: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2477): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
    09-08 10:45:27.177: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2477): java.lang.NullPointerException
    09-08 10:45:27.177: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2477):     at com.android.contacts.InstantDial.fillterQuickNums(InstantDial.java:230)
    09-08 10:45:27.177: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2477):     at com.android.contacts.InstantDial.setNumber(InstantDial.java:210)
    09-08 10:45:27.177: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2477):     at com.android.contacts.TwelveKeyDialer.afterTextChanged(TwelveKeyDialer.java:305)
    09-08 10:45:27.177: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2477):     at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:6286)
    09-08 10:45:27.177: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2477):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2704)
    09-08 10:45:27.177: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2477):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2565)
    09-08 10:45:27.177: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2477):     at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:71)
    09-08 10:45:27.177: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2477):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2540)
    09-08 10:45:27.177: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2477):     at android.widget.TextView.setTransformationMethod(TextView.java:1187)
    09-08 10:45:27.177: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2477):     at android.widget.TextView.applySingleLine(TextView.java:5924)
    09-08 10:45:27.177: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2477):     at android.widget.TextView.setInputType(TextView.java:2945)
    09-08 10:45:27.177: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2477):     at com.android.contacts.TwelveKeyDialer.updateEditText(TwelveKeyDialer.java:466)
    09-08 10:45:27.177: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2477):     at com.android.contacts.TwelveKeyDialer.access$400(TwelveKeyDialer.java:97)
    09-08 10:45:27.177: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2477):     at com.android.contacts.TwelveKeyDialer$3.run(TwelveKeyDialer.java:459)
    09-08 10:45:27.177: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2477):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    09-08 10:45:27.177: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2477):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    09-08 10:45:27.177: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2477):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    09-08 10:45:27.177: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2477):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
    09-08 10:45:27.177: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2477):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    09-08 10:45:27.177: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2477):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    09-08 10:45:27.177: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2477):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)
    09-08 10:45:27.177: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2477):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:635)
    09-08 10:45:27.177: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2477):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I literally have no idea why its doing this.  like i say ist only one 1 in 10 launches that fail.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.